# Are finalisers called when the last reference is garbage collected, or when Any reference is garbage collected?

Tags: julia, finalizer

The [julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/stdlib/base/?highlight=finalizer#Base.finalizer) say:

> finalizer(x, f)
>
> Register a function f(x) to be called when there are no
>   program-accessible references to x. The type of x must be a mutable
>   struct, otherwise the behavior of this function is unpredictable.

However, I seem to be observing that they are triggering when the first reference to my type  loses its last reference.

Consider:

```
using Base.Test
mutable struct Foo
    val
end
@testset "how do Finalisers work" begin let
    fin_calls = []

    a = Foo(1)
    b = a
    finalizer(a, _ -> push!(fin_calls, "a"))
    finalizer(b, _ -> push!(fin_calls, "b"))

    @test fin_calls == []
    a = 7
    gc()
    @test fin_calls == [] # Fails: Evaluated: Any["a", "b"] == Any[]
    #shouldn't trigger finaliser as still has 1 ref, or so I thought

    b=8
    gc()
    @test Set(fin_calls) == Set(["a", "b"]) #both finalizers should trigger
end end
```

There are 2 references to my `Foo(1)`, those being `a` and `b`

#### I would have expected  that:

- When `a` is changed to something else, nothing happens
- When `b` is also changed so something else, both registered `finalizers` trigger. Causing "a" and "b" both to be added to the `fin_calls` array.

#### Instead, what I am observing is:

I would have expected  that:

- When `a` is changed to something else, both registered `finalizers` trigger. Causing "a" and "b" both to be added to the `fin_calls` array.
- When `b` is also changed so something else, nothing further occurs.

**What is the correct way to understand what is going on?**
This is in julia 6.0

My ability to reproduce this seems varied.

- On original machine it showed for 0.6.0.
- On another machine:

  - 0.6.1 (-O2 default ) resulted in a failure of the finaliser not being called (which is OK, it is ok for finaliser to be called late).
  - 0.7-dev (-O0) resulted in a pass,
  - 0.7-dev (-O1 or higher) resulted in Failure due to both being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use a variable,
The garbage collector is free to collect a variable at any time after it is last used.

If you do not use a variable at all then the optimizer is free to never generate it in the actual code at all.

I believe that is what has occurred.
If I add some more uses of the variables the the behavour is as expected.

```
using Base.Test

"This function makes use of `xs` in a way no optimizer can possibly remove"
function use(xs...)
    mktemp() do fn, fh
        print(fh, xs)
    end
end


mutable struct Foo
    val
end

function foo()
    @testset "how do Finalisers work" begin let
        fin_calls = []

        a = Foo(1)
        b = a
        finalizer(a, _ -> push!(fin_calls, "a"))
        finalizer(b, _ -> push!(fin_calls, "b"))

        use(a,b)
        @test fin_calls == []
        a = 7
        gc()
        use(b)
        @test fin_calls == [] # Fails: Evaluated: Any["a", "b"] == Any[]
        #shouldn't trigger finaliser as still has 1 ref, or so I thought

        b=8
        gc()
        @test Set(fin_calls) == Set(["a", "b"]) #both finalizers should trigger
    end end
```

This code, for me gets to the final test and then fails as at that point `fin_calls` has never been called. because the garbage collector can choose not to run.

end